# HTML/Javascript - Access contents of the data tag of an <object>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, structure

What is the easiest way to access the data within the `<body>` tag in this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgNEP.jpg) using JavaScript/JQuery?

I need to return the content as a string, json or html file structure in my script. The file ("bib_chi.html") looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6gnk.jpg).

I don't know how to specify my query so that it returns the contents of the `<body>` tag.

What I've tried so far (and didn't work):

- `$("#bibTex");` see 1st image
- `$("#bibTex").contentDocument.body;`        returns empty `<body></body>`
- `$("#bibTex").contents();` returns a file structure that I don't know how to work with
- `$("#bibTex").text();` returns an empty string
- `$("#bibTex").html();` returns an empty string
- `$("#bibTex").innerHTML` returns 'undefined'

I am grateful for every piece of advise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('#bibTex').html()`? It's possible the DOM is being truncated as its invalid to have a nested `<html>` or `<body>` tags.

Comment: `$('#bibTex').text()` and `$('#bibTex').html()` both return either nothing or an empty string, can't really tell from the `console.log()`. It's just a blank field

Comment: Do the HTML and body tags really exist in your document, or do you only see them in the developer tool?

Comment: No, there are no `<html>` or `<body>` tags in the document. That's why it confused me in the first place to see the html structure in the browser console in the first place. They probably got added by the browser(?) because I saved the file as `.html`?

Comment: Have you tried to get the body also via jQuery with $("#bibTex").find("body") and the call text()=

Comment: Can you provide us a jsfiddle ?

Comment: What is the `$("#bibTex").contents()` file structure? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the DOM-Attribute innerHTML or the jQuery Method text().
For more information: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: `$("#bibTex").innerHTML` returns 'undefined'